# How can I check where my bitcoins have gone to in my app?

Tags: bitcoind

[image] help
I need to know where to go search my bitcoins after they entered my account on my bitcoin app...so far its two day still nothing showing....

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, what software you are using.

Comment: When did you send it? I mean how long has it been since you sent the bits?

Comment: If its been a reasonable time(e.g. 6+ hours), please let me know if you have access to the sender/receiving address? Then you can track your transaction via some blockchain explorer like [this one](https://explorer.bitcoin.com/btc).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the unimaginatively named "[bitcoin wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets/mobile/android/bitcoinwallet/)"

I would review the transaction details provided by the sender of the Bitcoins. If you have a transaction-id or receiving-address you can look it up on a [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) to see what is happening.

A few obvious possibilities to bear in mind

- insufficient mining fee
- incorrect recipient address
- problems with wallet configuration

  - not syncing with bitcoin network
  - private key not imported?